# show query results by category

Tags: php, mysql

I have a sql table "fournisseurs", for each line i have three column :

FRN_ID, FRN_RGN_ID, FRN_TYPE_ENTREE.

FRN_TYPE_ENTREE can be equal to "LES FONTAINES A VINS" , "LES BOUTEILLES" or "PRODUITS CONNEXE".

FRN_ID is the id of the producer.

FRN_RGN_ID is the id of the state. (Bordeaux, Alsace etc...).

I want to show something like this :

LES BOUTEILLES :

The ids of the states (FRN_RGN_ID)

LES FONTAINES A VIN :

The ids of the states (FRN_RGN_ID)

PRODUITS CONNEXES :

The ids of the states (FRN_RGN_ID)

For each line i have these columns (`FRN_ID`, `FRN_RGN_ID`, `FRN_TYPE_ENTREE`)

I want to do it in **PHP**.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fournisseur` (
  `FRN_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FRN_RGN_ID` text NOT NULL,
  `FRN_TYPE_ENTREE` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`FRN_ID`)
...
```

Comment: can you add the create table syntax ? u can get it with SHOW CREATE TABLE fournisseurs;

Comment: The posts you added below are [not valid answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). Stack Overflow has a question-and-answer format, not a discussion thread format. "Answer" means you're actually providing an answer to the question. It's not the same as "Reply" in a discussion forum.
Please read the [About](http://www.stackoverflow.com/about) page to get a better understanding of the site's format. To add updates to your question, you should edit the question rather than posting answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In php :

```
$query = 'SELECT DISTINCT FRN_TYPE_ENTREE,
                          FRN_RGN_ID            
          FROM Fournisseurs ORDER BY FRN_TYPE_ENTREE';
// exec the query & cie
$prev_type = null;
foreach($results as $result) {
    if($prev_type != $result['FRN_TYPE_ENTREE']) {
       $prev_type = $result['FRN_TYPE_ENTREE'];
       echo $result['FRN_TYPE_ENTREE'];
    } 

    echo $result['FRN_RGN_ID'];
}
```

Or

```
SELECT FRN_TYPE_ENTREE, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT FRN_RGN_ID) AS 'frn_rgn_ids'
FROM Fournisseurs
GROUP BY FRN_TYPE_ENTREE
```

Comment: i want to do it in PHP for showing the results. maybe with a group by or something ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **CASE** statements inside the query.

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN FRN_TYPE_ENTREE=`LES BOUTEILLES` then FRN_RGN_ID else NULL END AS 
`LES BOUTEILLES`, CASE WHEN FRN_TYPE_ENTREE=`LES FONTAINES A VINS` then FRN_RGN_ID 
else NULL END AS `LES FONTAINES A VINS`, CASE WHEN FRN_TYPE_ENTREE=`PRODUITS CONNEXES` 
then FRN_RGN_ID else NULL END AS `PRODUITS CONNEXES`   FROM  `fournisseur`
```

You`ll get a pivoted table or cross tabbed one for each or your categories:

```
LES BOUTEILLES  |  LES FONTAINES A VINS  |  PRODUITS CONNEXES
AUTRE              BORDEAUX
LOIRE              BORDEAUX
AUTRE              BORDEAUX  
LANGUEDOC ROUSSILLON
BORDEAUX           BORDEAUX
```

In **PHP** you can position each column as you want.

Comment: Please keep in mind data granularity, and hierarchies.  As far as I can see, many  different BOUTEILLES could belong to the same LES FONTAINES A VINS,  that way in some columns you`ll get many repetitions,  the same PARENT for each different CHILD.